# How to display contents in reverse order in <h:dataTable>

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, reverse

I am accepting data in Array and displaying it in the same screen using `<h:dataTable>`.
How can display contents in reverse order, i.e. show the latest entry in the first row?

Below is code can i display nonDox.non_List in reverse order

```
<h:body>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty dataBase}">
     <h:form id="nonDoxScanForm">
     <f:event listener="#{nonDox.validate_AccNo}" type="postValidate" />
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
     <table border="0"  class="InnerBox"    width="55%">
        <tr><th  colspan="7" align="Center" class="clsTitle">Non Dox Add</th></tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Delivery Date</td>
           <td >Consginee (F2) </td>
           <td>Weight (F3)</td>
           <td>SubBranch Code(F4)</td>
           <td >Consignment No (F10)</td>
           <td align="Center">(F12)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>  <p:calendar value="#{nonDox.delDate}" id="fDat" />    </td>
           <td><h:inputText size="20" id="fcon" value="#{nonDox.consignee}" /> </td>
           <td><h:inputText size="20" id="fweig" value="#{nonDox.weight}" >
           </h:inputText> </td>
           <td><h:inputText size="20" id="fsub" value="#{nonDox.subBranchCode}" >
           <f:validateLength  maximum="3"></f:validateLength>
           </h:inputText> </td>`enter code here`
           <td><h:inputText size="10" id="acno" value="#{nonDox.accNo}" onfocus="this.select()"  >
            </h:inputText>
           </td>
           <td> <h:commandButton value="Add" id="fAdd" action="#{nonDox.addAction}" onclick="return validate();"  />
           </td>
           <td> <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{nonDox.saveAction}" >
           </h:commandButton>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td colspan="7">
          <h:message for="acno"/>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
    <h:dataTable value="#{  nonDox.non_List}" var="o"
     styleClass="order-table"
     headerClass="order-table-header"
     rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row" width="55%"
     >
     <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Del Date</f:facet>
         #{o.cor_Date.substring(0, 10)}
     </h:column>
     <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">consignee</f:facet>
         #{o.consignee}
     </h:column>
     <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Weight</f:facet>
        #{o.weight}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
       <f:facet name="header">Rate</f:facet>
       #{o.rate}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
       <f:facet name="header">subBranchCode</f:facet>
       #{o.subBranchCode}
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header" >POD No</f:facet>
      #{o.accNo}
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>
      <h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{nonDox.deleteAction(o)}" />
   </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
 </h:form>
 <h:panelGroup >
     <h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty  dataBase}">
     <h1>Session Expired</h1>
     <h:link outcome="Login" target="CommonContent" >Login</h:link>
  </h:panelGroup>
  </h:body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using an `List` as in `new ArrayList<Item>()`, it's easy: use [`Collections#reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29):

```
private List<Item> data;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    data = service.list();
    Collections.reverse(data);
}

// ...
```

Just reference it in `<h:dataTable value="#{bean.data}">` the usual way.

If you're using an array as in `Item[]`, then you'd need to convert it to `List` first with help of [`Arrays#asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29), so that you can feed it to `Collections#reverse()`:

```
private List<Item> data;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Item[] items = service.array();
    data = Arrays.asList(items);
    Collections.reverse(data);
}

// ...
```

Or just rewrite the service method in such way that you don't need to perform this conversion step in the backing bean.

Key is, you shouldn't expect to perform this job in the view. You should just prepare the model in such way that it's exactly as what the view expects. The `<h:dataTable>` itself doesn't provide any facilities like that.

Comment: Can you @BalusC explain what is `service.array()` ? What is `service`

Comment: @Orbita: Just the business service class which interacts with the DB and returns the desired data. Usually an EJB. The code in my answer is purely exemplary. You may use a different class/variable/method name. But the logic is exactly the same.